# Modify JSon responce for @ManyToOne association using Jackson and Spring

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have two classes:

```
public class Team {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
        ...
}
public class Event {
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team homeTeam;

    @ManyToOne
    private Team guestTeam;
...
}
```

Controller:

```
public @ResponseBody List<Event> getAll() {...
}
```

Now I have Json:

```
[{"id":1,"homeTeam":{"id":2,"name":"Golden State"},"guestTeam":{"id":1,"name":"Philadelphia"},...
```

What I want:

```
[{"id":1,"homeTeam":"Golden State","guestTeam":"Philadelphia",...
```

How I can point Jackson to output only name of Team instead of full Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benoit's answer will not generate JSON of the desired form, it would produce something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"homeTeam":{"name":"Golden State"},"guestTeam":{"name":"Philadelphia"},...
```

Instead what you want to do is make your `Team` class look something like this:

```
public class Team {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    ...
}
```

This will produce the desired JSON:

```
[{"id":1,"homeTeam":"Golden State","guestTeam":"Philadelphia",...
```

But may require additional handling for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude all properties of the `Team` object except the `name` using : @JsonIgnoreProperties

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public String getPropertyToExclude() {
    return propertyToExclude;
}
```

So that Jackson will serialize only the Team name in the JSON.